# How can I project a new point onto a space created by PCA in matlab

Tags: matlab, pca, projection

I have a dataset of 30 variables and 60 observations. I perform PCA and keep the first 2 components.
I also perform PCA on another dataset and end up with a point that I need to project onto the space that I created from my first PCA. Is this possible? How could I do that?

Comment: Hi Selena, welcome to SO! As I understand, you have already performed the PCA successfully, is that right? If so, is [this R question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/how-to-project-a-new-vector-onto-pca-space) similar to yours?

Comment: @Vicky Hi there, thank you for commenting! Yes I have performed PCA on both datasets, but their dimensions are different, as I only need one single point in my graph. It is similar as I can understand, however I am still unable to implement it in my code. :(

Comment: Could you share a minimal working example of your code so far?